# Can someone explain what this is?

Tags: kitchens, ceiling, painting

Very new homebuyer, able and willing to learn the new ropes of home improvements, etc. Recently noticed that it that the paint is separating from the ceiling. Not sure what caused it however, it is getting cold in Texas wondering if anyone can offer some insight.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When the outside temp get colder and dryer it is not uncommon for building materials to shrink and minor cracks and gaps to manifest themselves.

From your pic, it looks like the seams of the ceiling drywall were not done well. I have to assume the bulkhead above the cabinets was not caulked well or not at all.

Since you say you are a new homeowner, it is a reasonable conclusion that some of the cosmetic repairs were not done up to professional standards. The solution is to cut the stretched paint and caulk with a flexible and paintable caulk. Depending on how big the gap is you may need to stuff in some foam backer rod. Then paint.

Watch for any other cracks or gaps that continue to grow. Those are signs of greater problems.

Comment: No caulk is going to survive that amount of shrinkage. That looks like it's moved far enough to even rip silicone.

Answer (score 1):

All of what @RMDman said and a little more. It looks like the renovators/flippers rehung those cabinets or installed the bulkhead after doing drywall installation/repair. Notice the poor taping job. Then they caulked between the ceiling and bulkhead. The cabinet then settled a bit breaking away from the caulk and paint. Clean up the crack and re caulk with a good silicone caulk. Don't use the cheap stuff, it'll just crack again.

Comment: Agree. If it's going to get colder/dryer before spring, I'd wait & do it at the 'worst' moment, so the silicone is then only ever under compression, next year.

Comment: Be sure whatever caulk you use is "paintable".